# PHP Version for latest Snowflake ODBC version (3.2.0)

Tags: php, linux, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, version

Currently, I am using Snowflake ODBC version `2.23.0`, and as of February 1, 2024, the latest minimum supported version is `2.24.5`. I intend to upgrade, but before doing so, I would like to know the PHP version supported for the latest Snowflake ODBC version, specifically `3.2.0`.

The commands I used for installing Snowflake ODBC and PHP are outlined below:

```
  # Backup your php.ini file
    - mv /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.bk.ini 
  # Download and install the version of the Snowflake ODBC driver
    - wget https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/latest/snowflake_linux_x8664_odbc-2.23.0.tgz
    - gunzip snowflake_linux_x8664_odbc-2.23.0.tgz
    - tar -xvf snowflake_linux_x8664_odbc-2.23.0.tar
  # Install the updated driver
    - sudo apt-get -y install unixodbc
    - cd snowflake_odbc
    - sudo bash unixodbc_setup.sh
  # Install php5-odbc package
    - sudo apt-get -y install php5-odbc
  # Restore your original php.ini file
    - mv /etc/php5/cli/php.bk.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

I have not found any official documentation specifying the PHP version supported for the latest Snowflake ODBC version. I want to ensure whether upgrading PHP is necessary or if PHP5 is sufficient for working with the latest Snowflake ODBC version.

Comment: When I look at the [PHP PDO driver for Snowflake](https://github.com/snowflakedb/pdo_snowflake?tab=readme-ov-file#prerequisites), they require PHP 8.2, 8.1 or 8.0 and support for PHP 7.4 or lower is deprecated. ODBC is different, because of the driver model, and might be more flexible when it comes to PHP versions.

Comment: PHP5 is EOL since years and should no longer be used